# Show Image on Hover code Not working

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to create an effect where when the mouse hovers over a link a specific image is shown. here is what I have so far.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var mouseIsOver = function(what) {
    return $(what + ":hover");
  }

  // and 
  var image_location = {
    c1: "http://carreviewwebsite.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Concept-Car-Tarantula.jpg",
    c2: "http://blogs-images.forbes.com/steveodland/files/2012/02/maserati-birdcage-concept.jpg",
    c3: "http://www.dieselstation.com/wallpapers/albums/Honda/Concepts-Tokyo-Auto-Show-2011/honda-concepts-tokyo-auto-show-2011-widescreen-08.jpg",
    c4: "http://conceptlux.com/wp-content/gallery/bmw-zx-6-2015-concept/BMW-ZX-6-2015-Concept-100.jpg",
    c5: "http://cdn.designrfix.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/09/design-of-concept-cars-29.jpg"
  };

  var link;
  var pathToImage;
  var xOff = -20;
  var yOff = 15;

  // select the right image for the right link

  if (mouseIsOver('#c1')) {
    link = $("#c1");
    pathToImage = image_location[c1];
  } else if (mouseIsOver("c2")) {
    link = $("#c2");
    pathToImage = paths["c2"];
  } else {
    link = $("#c3");
    pathToImage = paths["c3"];
  }

  //the hover effect

  link.hover(function(e) {
    $("body").append("<p id='hover-img'><img src='" + pathToImage + "'/></p>");
    $("#hover-img")
      .css("position", "absolute")
      .css("top", (e.pageY - yOff) + "px")
      .css("left", (e.pageX + xOff) + "px")
      .fadeIn("fast");
  }, function() {
    $("#hover-img").remove();
  });

  link.mousemove(function(e) {
    $("#hover-img")
      .css("top", (e.pageY - yOff) + "px")
      .css("left", (e.pageX + xOff) + "px");

  });

});
```

```css
#hover-img img {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" id="c1">car 1</a>

<hr />

<a href="#" id="c2">car 2</a>

<hr />

<a href="#" id="c3">car 3</a>

<hr />

<a href="#" id="c4">car 4</a>

<hr />

<a href="#" id="c5">car 5</a>
```

in the code the first function is what I use to detect what link I am hovering over.
Then I have the image locations stored in an object for access

When I test it it sometimes works but only for one link. anyone have a better idea

Comment: Will these pictures and links be dynamic or static?

Comment: Why not just use CSS to display them on hover of the link?

Comment: Are you looking for something like this http://jsbin.com/zugecumeco/1/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: if i was to make them dynamic is this code viable. is there anything i can modify to make it work

Comment: Yes that's how i want it to be but once the mouse moves off the link it must be removed and the image must not push on any other elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're only checking where the mouse is when the page first loads. Instead, you can check the hover and mousemove events on the document and delegate them to links. With this method, you don't even need to wait until the DOM is loaded.

```js
var image_location = {
    c1: "http://carreviewwebsite.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Concept-Car-Tarantula.jpg",
    c2: "http://blogs-images.forbes.com/steveodland/files/2012/02/maserati-birdcage-concept.jpg",
    c3: "http://www.dieselstation.com/wallpapers/albums/Honda/Concepts-Tokyo-Auto-Show-2011/honda-concepts-tokyo-auto-show-2011-widescreen-08.jpg",
    c4: "http://conceptlux.com/wp-content/gallery/bmw-zx-6-2015-concept/BMW-ZX-6-2015-Concept-100.jpg",
    c5: "http://cdn.designrfix.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/09/design-of-concept-cars-29.jpg"
  };

  var xOff = 15;
  var yOff = -20;

  $(document).on("mouseenter mouseleave", "a", function(e) {
    if (e.type === "mouseenter") {
      var pathToImage = image_location[this.id];
      $("body").append("<p id='hover-img'><img src='" + pathToImage + "'/></p>");
      $("#hover-img").fadeIn("fast");
    } else {
      $("#hover-img").remove();
    }
  }).on("mousemove", "a", function(e) {
    $("#hover-img")
      .css("top", (e.pageY - yOff) + "px")
      .css("left", (e.pageX + xOff) + "px");
  });
```

```css
#hover-img {
  position: fixed;
  display: none;
}
#hover-img img {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="#" id="c1">car 1</a>

<hr />

<a href="#" id="c2">car 2</a>

<hr />

<a href="#" id="c3">car 3</a>

<hr />

<a href="#" id="c4">car 4</a>

<hr />

<a href="#" id="c5">car 5</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

Changed appending , removing new image at each `mouseover` event . Utilized background-image to cache image ; not requested from server at each `mouseover`. Changed `"left": (e.pageX + xOff) + "px"` to `"left": (e.pageX + yOff) + "px"` to display image to right of cursor, instead of over `a` element.

```js
  $(function() {
// and 
var image_location = {
  c1: "http://carreviewwebsite.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Concept-Car-Tarantula.jpg",
  c2: "http://blogs-images.forbes.com/steveodland/files/2012/02/maserati-birdcage-concept.jpg",
  c3: "http://www.dieselstation.com/wallpapers/albums/Honda/Concepts-Tokyo-Auto-Show-2011/honda-concepts-tokyo-auto-show-2011-widescreen-08.jpg",
  c4: "http://conceptlux.com/wp-content/gallery/bmw-zx-6-2015-concept/BMW-ZX-6-2015-Concept-100.jpg",
  c5: "http://cdn.designrfix.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/09/design-of-concept-cars-29.jpg"
};

var elems = $($.map(image_location, function(src, i) {
  return $("<div />", {
    "class": i,
    "css": {
      "background-image":"url(\""+src+"\")",
      "background-repeat":"no-repeat",
      "background-size":"cover",
      "width":"200px",
      "height":"200px",
      "display":"none",
      "position":"absolute"
    }
  })[0]
}));

$("body").append(elems);

var xOff = -20;
var yOff = 15;

// select the right image for the right link
//the hover effect
$("a")
.on({"mouseover": function(e) {
  var el = elems.filter("." + this.id);
  if (el.is(":hidden")) { el.fadeToggle("fast") };

}, "mouseleave":function() {
  elems.filter("[class="+ this.id + "]").finish().fadeToggle("fast"); 

}, "mousemove": function(e) {
   elems.filter(":visible") 
   .css({"top": (e.pageY - yOff) + "px",
         "left": (e.pageX + yOff) + "px"})
}});

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<a href="#" id="c1">car 1</a>
<hr />
<a href="#" id="c2">car 2</a>
<hr />
<a href="#" id="c3">car 3</a>
<hr />
<a href="#" id="c4">car 4</a>
<hr />
<a href="#" id="c5">car 5</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a CSS example of what I was referring to. This preserves the space for the photos (nothing is shifted when they are displayed) without showing the photos until hover of the link.

#### HTML:

```
<div>
    <a href="#">One</a>
    <img src="//placehold.it/200x250" />
</div>
<div>
    <a href="#">Two</a>
    <img src="//placehold.it/200x250" />
</div>
<div>
    <a href="#">Three</a>
    <img src="//placehold.it/200x250" />
</div>
<div>
    <a href="#">Four</a>
    <img src="//placehold.it/200x250" />
</div>
```

#### CSS:

```
a {
    display: block;
}

a + img {
    visibility: hidden;
}

a:hover + img {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/hopkins_matt/oed45h5e/

Comment: I see the answer you accepted, and everything appears to be pretty doable in CSS without JS.

Comment: The main difference is in OP's example the image follows the mouse

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps. I had to create a new HTML and CSS template but you can follow the same format. I had to implement this in my own way as your question didn't provide a fiddle but it achieves the central purpose of showing an image on the hovering of a specific link:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n6zvkw5a/1/)

**jQuery**

```
function hoverExampleFunction(){
  var pictureHandler = '#';
  var hoverHandler = $('.child');
  var index = 0;    
  hoverHandler.hover(function(){   
     index = $(this).index();
     $(pictureHandler+index).animate({opacity:1},200);
  },function(){
     $(pictureHandler+index).css('opacity','0');
  });
}

hoverExampleFunction();
```

**HTML**

```
<div id = "cars">
<img id="0" src="http://crispme.com/wp-content/uploads/lamborghini_aventador-1920x1200.jpg"/>
<img id="1" src="http://news.bbcimg.co.uk/media/images/70996000/jpg/_70996728_70996727.jpg"/>
<img id="2" src="http://cdn.wegotthiscovered.com/wp-content/uploads/Project-Cars.jpg"/>
</div>

<div id = "hover-tabs">
<h1 class="child">First Pic</h1>
<h1 class="child">Second Pic</h1>
<h1 class="child">Third Pic</h1>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
img{
  width:100%;
  height:500px;
  position:absolute;
  padding:0;
  opacity:0;
}

#cars{
  background:black;
  height:500px;
  width:100%;
  padding:0;
}

h1{
  display:inline;
  margin:0 auto;
  padding:0px 30px 0px 30px;
  background:orange;
  cursor:pointer;
}
```